# Whats wrong with my hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on an Acer Aspire one D225, and recently replaced my hard drive to a 60gb SSD. The first day I did, I got a kernal panic error about an I/O error to a superblock. It only happened once, but since then the GUI periodically crashes and does not restart, requiring a hard shutdown and reboot. I'm experienced on Windows, but new to and lost with Linux. The built in self-tests on the drive have not shown anything yet, nothing starting with the SMART data, but the system log is repeating the following every couple of seconds.

```
[  315.428143] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310) ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (4)
[  315.467150] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (4)
[  315.467841] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  315.467860] ata1: EH complete
[  317.001617] ata1: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x40d0800 action 0xe frozen
[  317.001637] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400040, connection status changed
[  317.001652] ata1: SError: { HostInt PHYRdyChg CommWake 10B8B DevExch }
[  317.001671] ata1: hard resetting link
[  317.896151] ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[  317.901885] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (4)
[  317.911867] ata1.00: unexpected _GTF length (4)
[  317.912521] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[  317.912540] ata1: EH complete
[  319.433541] ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x90000 action 0xe frozen
[  319.433553] ata1: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
```

I don't even know were to begin, is my hard drive bad, or is this something that a reformat/re-install will fix?

Comment: what ended up happening with your drive?